# SQLAlchemy: TypeError using comparison operator in update

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform a comparison in a SQLAlchemy bulk update query. Arithmetic operators work, but doing a comparison causes a vague TypeError. The basic example below hopefully highlights the problem.

```
class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    is_passing = Column(Boolean, nullable=True)

def is_passing(score, passing_score):
    if score >= passing_score:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    s = Session(engine)
    query = s.query(Student)  
    query.update(
            {
                "is_passing": is_passing(Student.score, 65.0)
            },
            synchronize_session=False,
       )
```

If I run the query building a list of updated values, I can accomplish what I need to do, but it doesn't explain the error.

```
updated_mappings = [{"id": row.id, "is_passing": is_passing(row.score, 65.0)}
                    for row in query]
s.bulk_update_mappings(Student, updated_mappings)
```

Resulting error message:

```
<ipython-input-4-4914ec21fc1f> in is_passing(score, passing_score)
     41 
     42 def is_passing(score, passing_score):
---> 43     if score >= passing_score:
     44         return True
     45     else:    
~/Envs/pandas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py in __bool__(self)
   2991             return self.operator(hash(self._orig[0]), hash(self._orig[1]))
   2992         else:
-> 2993             raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
   2994 
   2995     __nonzero__ = __bool__

TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

Comment: I guess that `score >= passing_score` here doesn't do really a comparison but creates a boolean expression which can be evaluated by SQLAlchemy (or underlying database) later. So you should just return `score >= passing_score` in `is_passing`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! I think your guess is right. It wasn't the comparison operator that was the problem, but forcing the score to be evaluated in the if statement.

Comment: In my actual work, I'm using bisect which does a comparison internally. I'll have to go with my new solution, but at least I understand why. Thanks again!